# Proving the second isomorphism theorem for groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

This is the assertion that I have in mind when I write "second isomorphism theorem for groups":

> If $K$ and $N$ are subgroups of a group $G$, with $N$ normal in $G$,
>   then $K /(N \cap K) \cong NK/N$.

I think that this assertion can be proven by considering the application $f \colon K \to NK/N$ determined by the *rule* $f(k) = Nk$, and showing that it is an epimorphism whose kernel is equal to $N \cap K$.

Do you know why it is that when some authors try to prove this result, instead of simply proceeding as above, they start off by considering the projection $\pi \colon G \to G/N$ and then restrict it to $K$? In my humble opinion, it is much more direct to analyze the application $f$ right from the start...

Comment: A lot of expositions of group theory are overworked.  (I've read that it's to solve a social problem: elevate the authority of the subject.)  On the other hand, the approach of restricting the context from a larger set sometimes (though not in this case) gives results otherwise unattainable.  So, the author's intent may be to cultivate that approach in the reader's mind.

Part I of Alekseev's *Abel's theorem in problems and solutions* is the best exposition I know.

Comment: Check out also the bottom of page 87 in [Rotman](http://www.math.hcmuns.edu.vn/~nvdong/DaiSoDaiCuong/Advanced%20Modern%20Algebra%20-%20Joseph%20J.%20Rotman.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The map $K\to NK/N$ you defined in the first place is exactly the same map as written at the end of your post: the restriction of $G\to G/N$ to $K$, whose image is clearly $NK/N$.

Comment: Yes, but this is not exactly what I was asking...